# Mathematics induction (exponential divisible by 2304)

Tags: induction

$7^{2n} -48n - 1$ is divisible by 2304 for all $n \in N$

so I did, P(n) : $7^{2n}-48n-1=2304k$ (k meaning there is an integer which will depend on n)

Prove base case $P(1): 7^2 - 48(1)-1 = 0$, proving that $k=0$ in the meaning of 'divides'

$n=k+1$

$7^{2(k+1)}-48(k+1)-1 = 2304l$ (l being for some integer)

I don't know how to proceed any further. could someone show me whats next?

thanks alot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$7^{2n} -48n - 1|2304$$
$$7^{2n+2} -48(n+1) - 1=49\cdot7^{2n}-48n-49$$
$$=49(7^{2n} -48n - 1)+49\cdot48n-48n$$
$$=49(7^{2n} -48n - 1)+48\cdot48n$$
$$=49(7^{2n} -48n - 1)+2304n$$

Answer (score 0):

We want to show that  $7^{2k+2}-48k-48-1$ is divisible by $2304$, which is $48^2$.

Our expression is equal to
$$49(7^{2k}-48k-1)+(49)(48k+1)-48k-48-1.$$
Now a little manipulation will do it. We get $49(7^{2k}-48k-1)+48^2k$.